# Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout (tried all solutions)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I have looked everywhere for solution and nothing works. Running xamarin 3.5. Action bar won't seem to load and goes into exception when I try and set the content. I have no idea what more can be done. I have tried setting to `NoActionBar`, then deleting obj and bin folders, clean and rebuilding solution.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="0dp">
    <android.support.v7.widget.ToolBar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/toolbarAWD"
        app:theme="@style/CustomToolBarTheme"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>

  <style name="MainTheme" parent="MainTheme.Base">
  </style>
  <!-- Base theme applied no matter what API -->
  <style name="MainTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!--If you are using revision 22.1 please use just windowNoTitle. Without android:-->
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <!--We will be using the toolbar so no need to show ActionBar-->
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <!-- Set theme colors from http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html#color-color-palette -->
    <!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">#2196F3</item>
    <!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar -->
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#1976D2</item>
    <!-- colorAccent is used as the default value for colorControlActivated
         which is used to tint widgets -->
    <item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
    <!-- You can also set colorControlNormal, colorControlActivated
         colorControlHighlight and colorSwitchThumbNormal. -->
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>

    <item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/AppCompatDialogStyle</item>
  </style>

  <style name="AppCompatDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
  </style>
  <style name="CustomToolBarTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#333333</item>
    <item name="android:background">#aaaaaa</item>

  </style>
</resources>
```

```cs
[Activity (Label = "Some", Icon = "@drawable/icon", Theme="@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;
        SetTheme(Resource.Style.CustomToolBarTheme);
        base.OnCreate (bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.ActionBar);
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init (this, bundle);
        LoadApplication (new Some.App ());
    }
}
```

breaks into an exception when trying to load the `SetContentView` method.

Comment: what excpetion? add the LogCat message please.

Comment: the exception is the title of this post. I also forgot to add that im using api 19

Comment: yes but try to add more details, probably your problem is the theme, you can see the cause into the LogCat message, look for "Caused by"....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> android.support.v7.widget.ToolBar

is not correct,
change to

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/toolbarAWD"
    app:theme="@style/CustomToolBarTheme"
/>
```